# syslog message format question

Tags: rsyslog

is there a way with rsyslog or syslog-ng to allow tab delimited messages? I'm currently using rsyslog and the c syslog() function to generate syslog messages from within my app.  The problem is that I use \t and they get translated into #011 when I view the logs.  Ideally I'd like to have the other control chars translated except tab.  is something like this possible?

Comment: You might want to ask this on Stack Overflow instead. Sounds like a developer question.  That being said, what app are you using to view the logs?

Answer (score 2):

syslog-ng will pass tabs

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can with syslog-ng - not sure about rsyslog.
To do it in syslog-ng, you simply add a \t in the tokens.

The syslog tool I use employs tab delimiters, here's the config for it:

```
destination d_logzilla {
   program("/www/logzilla/scripts/db_insert.pl"
   template("$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY $HOUR:$MIN:$SEC\t$HOST\t$PRI\t$PROGRAM\t$MSGONLY\n")
   template_escape(yes)
   );
};
```

And here's a short video on how to configure syslog-ng from their site:
http://www.logzilla.pro/syslog-ng-configuration